# How to grab hold of a UITextField's placeholder outside of the closure it was declared in?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an alert view that shows up with a text field. I want to be able to change the placeholder of the text field to "Enter something here" when user clicks on the "Add Item" button if the string entered is empty. Any idea how to achieve this effect?

[image: Alert View]

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class TodoListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold)]
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.29, green: 0.63, blue: 0.82, alpha: 1)
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - TableView DataSource Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = itemArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    //MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == .checkmark{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
        } else {
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK: - Add New Items
    
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { action in
            if textField.text != "" {
                self.itemArray.append(textField.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                //change name of placeholder here
            }
        }
        alert.addTextField { alertTextField in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If the user clicks the button the alert will be dismissed so there would be no point in changing the placeholder text. I would set the delegate on the textField and disable the button if the text is empty. That way the user can't continue until they enter some text.

Comment: @RobC I tried `action.isEnabled = false` in the else block but it did not work. How else may i go about achieving the effect you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Get the textfield from the alert

```
 } else {
    alert.textFields?.first?.placeholder = "Enter something here"
 }
```

but you have to again present the alert controller.
Like this

```
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item:", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { action in
            if textField.text != "" {
                self.itemArray.append(textField.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                alert.textFields?.first?.placeholder = "Enter something here"
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        alert.addTextField { alertTextField in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```